# Is it possible to have a seperate TEMP path for Windows and Applications

Tags: windows, files

I want windows to use c:/temp as its temp folder.
I want all other applications to use d:/temp as their temp folders.

I believe this is not possible, or is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try editing environment before you start the application. You can write a batch script.

```
set TEMP=D:\temp
call application.exe
```

That might not work in case when application doesn't read the location of a TEMP folder from environment (e.g. it reads it from registry instead).

Comment: I cant and don't want to write batch files for all applications.